# Web scraping advice/help with java for android app!

Tags: android, web-scraping

I've heard about web scraping software that can take data from a webpage. i'm building an android app and I want to take information from this site www.menupages.ie

All I need is the names of the restaurants, and typing them in myself would be very tedious.

Can someone tell me how i'd go about doing this in eclipse, what methods i need etc. 
I dont know anything about it.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Did this help you at all or do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post: [Client-side Web Scraping](http://zscraper.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/client-side-web-scraping/).
Coincidentally, it talks about scraping [menupages.com](http://menupages.com)